# Working of dot operator when applied to objects

Tags: java

I was going through the working principles of the dot operator, which is the same as the * operator in C++, that is they both solve our purpose of dereferencing. When we apply dot to some class, or some object, then we enter the heap of the class/object, and have an access to the static variables or methods of class, and instance variables as well in the case of methods.

Now my doubt is that while I'm applying some method to an object by using the dot operator, that is, now I'm able to use the data stored inside the instance variables inside my methods. But now when I try and change the data of those instance variables, it tends to change. From what I know I can't change the data inside the methods of languages like java where things work pass by value.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Non-static methods that you call have the ability to modify instance variables.

Comment: You certainly can modify the data of instance variables, if you mean things like `foo.bar = baz`.

Comment: In Java, the value of *instances* **are** *references*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I know I can't change the data inside the methods of languages like java where things work pass by value.

Java is pass by value ... but in the case of reference types (arrays or instances of classes), the values are references.

The dot "operator" is performing an operation on a reference.

In Java, you normally just forget about the fact that there is a reference there and (mentally) treat the object and the reference to the object as being the same thing.  (There is a reference available, even in the case of instance method referring to the fields if the current object ... it is `this`, and you are using it implicitly.)

This is different to C++.  In C++, object types and reference (pointer) typed are distinct, and their values (objects and references) are likewise distinct.  You can create, pass, and use, an object without having a reference to it.  And the compiler does not prevent you from having a reference that doesn't actually point to an object.  The behavior of the latter is undefined ...

Also in C++, you can create and pass references to things that are not objects.  For example, you can pass a reference to a variable.  You can't do that in Java.